# AngularJS ngIf prevents finding element inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive that includes an `ngIf` and I would like to modify some of the DOM inside the `ngIf` in the directive link function. Unfortunately it seems that `ngIf` prevents me from finding DOM elements within it in the link function.

Here is the code for the directive:

```
directive('column', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/column.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        column: '='
      },
      controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.editing = true;
        $scope.toggleEditing = function () {
          $scope.editing = !$scope.editing;
        };

      }],
      link: function postLink(scope, element) {
        var select = element.find('select');
        console.log(select); // See if it can find the select element
        // var types = scope.column.types();
        // add types as options to the select element
      }
    };
  });
```

And here is the simplified html of the directive:

```
<div class="column">
    <div>{{ column.title }}</div>
    <form name="columnForm" role="form" ng-if="editing">
        <select></select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the link to the jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/dedalusj/Y49Xx/1/

The `element.find` call in the link function returns an empty array but as soon as I remove the `ngIf` from the form it returns the proper select DOM element. I have the feeling that I'm doing this the wrong way.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answers but I found another solution. I simply created another directive that encapsulate the form, added it to the `column` directive template with `ng-if="editing"`.

The form directive doesn't have it's own scope so it effectively operates out of the `column` directive scope and has always access to the `select` element because it's inside its DOM tree. I pay the cost of an extra directive but I don't have to use the `$timeout` hack. I created a new jsFiddle to illustrate the solution http://jsfiddle.net/dedalusj/nx3vX/1/

Thanks @Michael but I can't simply use the `ng-option` because the `types` array comes from an XML file and its elements are other angular.element objects which cannot be inserted easily with `ng-option`.

Comment: ngIf prevents the element from being added to the DOM. You might have more luck with ngShow.

Comment: Yeah that's true but the form can be contain several other directives and the directive it's part of appears multiple times in the document so it would be better not to have it all in the DOM. I was hoping there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 12):

The `ngIf` directive works by using Angular's transclusion feature. What happens during the compile/link cycle is:

1. The content inside the `ngIf` is removed from the DOM when it is compiled
2. Angular runs the link functions. The `ngIf`'s link function is run before
   the link function of the directive using it. When `ngIf`'s link function
   runs, it uses `$scope.$watch()` to watch the value of the `ng-if`
   attribute.
3. Your directive's link function runs, at this point the content of the `ngIf` is not part of the DOM
4. The watch set up in step (2) is called, and `ngIf` will then call the `$transclude` function to insert the contents of the `ngIf` into the DOM if the `ng-if` attribute value is truthy.
5. Any watch functions, `$timeout` calls or use of `$scope.$evalAsync` that you registered in your directive's link function will run.

So if you want to access elements inside the `ngIf`'s content, the code needs to run *after* step 4 above. This means that any functions registered with `$scope.$watch`, `$timeout` or `$scope.$evalAsync` in your directive's link function will work. For a one-time piece of setup code, I would probably opt for `$scope.$evalAsync`:

```
angular.directive('yourDirective', function () {
  return {
    ...
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      scope.$evalAsync(function () {
        // code that runs after conditional content
        // with ng-if has been added to DOM, if the ng-if
        // is enabled
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Here is a Plunker which demonstrates this in action with a customized version of `ngIf` based on the source from Angular 1.4.x: http://plnkr.co/edit/MI7hF0eKDS8DmpP9yHnw?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

As @moderndegree has said, `ngIf` removes the element it's applied to from the DOM, so you won't be able to find it when it's not there. But, you could write your directive in a way to workaround that:

```
controller: function ($scope, $element, $timeout) {
  $scope.toggleEditing = function () {
    $scope.editing = !$scope.editing;
    $timeout(function() {
      var select = $element.find('select');
      select.append('<option>Value 1</option>')
            .append('<option>Value 2</option>')
            .append('<option>Value 3</option>');
    });            
  };
}
```

Updated jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y49Xx/3/).

The trick here is to delay the `find()` call by using `$timeout` with a 0 interval in order to wait for Angular to update the DOM.

**UPDATE**

After giving some more thought to your code, I realize that perhaps you can let Angular do the hard work for you:

**Javascript**

```
directive('column', function () {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'views/column.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      column: '='
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.editing = true;
      $scope.toggleEditing = function () {
        $scope.editing = !$scope.editing;
      };
    }],
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="column">
  <div>{{ column.title }}</div>
  <form name="columnForm" role="form" ng-if="editing">
    <select ng-model="type" ng-options="type for type in column.types"></select>
  </form>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y49Xx/4/)

Now you don't need to worry about finding the `select` element at the right time and populating it. Angular does all of that for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can put your code from the link function inside $timeout.

```
$timeout(function(){
     var select = element.find('select');
     console.log(select);
});
```

Don't forget to inject $timeout in your directive

```
directive('column', function ($timeout) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this same issue and i was able to resolve it using ng-show, this prevents this issue because ngIf removes the element it's applied to the DOM, so you won't be able to find it when it's not there.

so in your case:

```
<div class="column">
<div>{{ column.title }}</div>
<form name="columnForm" role="form" ng-show="editing">
    <select></select>
</form>
```

will work OK.

Cheers.

Comment: With using of `ng-show` element will be loaded into the DOM, and in most cases it doesn't needed